# Why Object.getPrototypeOf(5) and 5.__proto__ are not same?

Tags: javascript

As we know that `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === obj.__proto__`  for an object but if we check this for number. These two are not same. Can anyone explain reason for this?

When I am doing `Object.getPrototypeOf(5)` I am getting Number constructor and while doing

```
5.__proto__
```

in console getting syntax error

Comment: Try `(5).__proto__`

Comment: @Pointy It's working. Why we need to put this in parentheses

Comment: Because `5.` looks like the start of a number like `5.25`